# LDAP Auth with NTLMv2 invalidCredential

Tags: ldap, windows-authentication, ntlm, ntlm-authentication

I want to set the NTLMv2 authentication on windows policy (secpol.msc)

In fact I set it this way:

```
Local Policies -> Security Options
Network Security: Lan manager authentication Level: Send NTLMv2 only.
```

When I want check this by Wireshark capture I view that che package failure. In fact on these lines I read that the authentication was failure.

```
LDAP - bindResponse(8) "<ROOT>" | NTLMSPP_NEGOTIATEsasl
LDAP - bindResponse(8) saslBindProgress, NTLMSPP_CHALLENGE
LDAP - bindRequest(9) "<ROOT>", NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: ITXXXX\User011sasl
LDAP - bindResponse(9)invalidCredentials (8009030C; LdapErr: DSID-0C09053E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1)
LDAP - unbindRequest(10)
```

Why this?

How I can resolve this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

52e is just bad password  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631

This is not a fail to negotiate or such.